# Laravel 10 custom rule

Tags: laravel-validation, laravel-10

I want to create a custom rule in Laravel 10. I used php artisan rule:make ValidPackageItem, and this class is generated

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;

class ValidPackageItems implements ValidationRule
{
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(string): \Illuminate\Translation\PotentiallyTranslatedString  $fail
     */
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and used it in the controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
            [
                'items' => 'required|valid_package_items'
            ]
        );
```

while now calling this function, i get this error

```
App\Rules\ValidPackageItems::validate(): Argument #3 ($fail) must be of type Closure, array given
```

I cant even know what is the validator is passing to this custom rule to know the problem, even after i changed the

```
* @param  \Closure(string): \Illuminate\Translation\PotentiallyTranslatedString  $fail
```

to \Closure(array): it does not solve it, and i remove the Closure declaration and make it just $fail , it goes into the class but the Validator always throw and error message even if the data is correct

I used to use invokable rules, but its depreciated in Laravel 10

anyone know a solution ? thanks in advance

I wanted to make a custom validation rule in Laravel X10 but i got an error
I expect the error to be solved and i can customize my rule

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution guys, the problem on how you invoke with the validation call

just run `php artisan rule:make ValidatePackageItems`

and the class generated, after that you have to call it this way

```
'items' => ['required', new ValidPackageItem()]
```

I was registering the validation rule in the `Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in the boot method, was trying to call it this way

`items => 'required,valid_package_items,some_condition`

as you saw, I dont really know if the problem was into registration & invoking or something else, but I got no time to try with registration.